# How to sperate the attribute values using comma?

Tags: magento-1.9

To display the configurable attribute in cart popup i have given the below coding:

```
    <p class="attri-value">  
        <?php $options = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct()); ?>
        <?php $product = $_item->getProduct(); ?>
     <?php 
            foreach($options['attributes_info'] as $key => $value){ 
            echo ' '.$value['value'];
            } 
    ?>
   </p>
```

Now when the attribute values are getting displayed, the values arw displyed like `,pink,M` I want it to get displayed like `pink,M` . I just want to diplay the comma only in between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following way:

```
$attributes = [];
foreach($options['attributes_info'] as $key => $value){
    if($value['value']) {
        $attributes[] = $value['value'];
    }
}
echo implode(',', $attributes);
```